# Create anonymous function dynamically?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I'm working on simple evolutionary AI. I need to generate an anonymous function dynamically. For it I have a list of conditions and actions:

```
   var conditions = [
    function () { return enemyNear(), }, 
    function () { return mySpeed() > 5; }, 
    function () { return 1 === 1; }];
   var actions = [
      function () { return alert('walk'); },
      function () { return alert('jump'); } 
      function () { return alert('attack'); } ]
```

The code chooses one of each to generate a new function:

```
condition = conditions [Math.floor(Math.random()*conditions .length)];
actions = conditions [Math.floor(Math.random()*actions .length)];
```

Provided it the chosen condition is `enemyNear()` and the chosen action is `walk()`, how can I generate the simple anonymous function?

```
behavior = function() {
    if(enemyNear()) {
        walk();
    }
}
```

I can change the way the arrays are saved if needed. How can this be done?

All characters `behaviors` are called inside a loop like this:

```
for(i=0,i<chars.length,i++) {
chars[i].behavior.call();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you already call the functions when you place them inside the array. `walk` is a reference to the function, while `walk()` calls the function and the return value is used instead.

Comment: I imagined the functions weren't saved correctly inside the array, I can change how they are saved if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, inside of the arrays you will need to have a *reference* to the condition and action function. Right now, you are calling them, so they basically are the same as a useless array like:

```
conditions = [true, false, true];
actions = [undefined, undefined, undefined];
```

I would correct it to something like this:

```
var conditions = [enemyNear, 
  function() { return mySpeed() > 5 }, 
  function(){ return true; }];
var actions = [walk, attack, jump];
```

And then you can create a function that generates a behavior:

```
function generateBehavior(){
  var condition = conditions[Math.floor(Math.random() * conditions.length)];
  var action = actions[Math.floor(Math.random() * actions.length)];
  return function() {
    if(condition()) {
      action();
    }
  }
}
```

You can see it in action on this [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SeXZj/2/).

Comment: this works perfectly. It's really outside the original question, but is there a way to modify a function later on? EG: add a second condition? Just a though but it's posible to turn it into a string (do whatever I want with it) and turn it back into a function so I avoid eval? It would really be the best to be able to do this since using a string would give me a lot of versitility

Comment: @Liso22 Instead of `if(condition())`, you could instead pick an index from a conditions array and do `if(conditions[i])` and then change `conditions[i]` to a different function

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way would be to only put functions inside the arrays:

```
var conditions = [
    enemyNear, 
    function () { return mySpeed() > 5; }, 
    function () { return 1 === 1; 
}];
var actions = [walk, attack, jump];
```

Then you could define `behave` as something like:

```
var behave = function(condition, action) {
    if(condition()) {
        action();
    }
}
```

And use it like for example:

```
behave(conditions[2], actions[1]);
```

Here, `2` and `1` could be a randomly generated number like this:

```
var getRandomInt = function (min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

var actRandomly = function (conditions, actions) {
    behave(
        conditions[getRandomInt(0, conditions.length -1)],
        actions[getRandomInt(0, actions.length -1)]
    );
};
```

Call it like:

```
actRandomly(conditions, actions);
```

Of course this only presents the idea, and is not neatly organized.

For the fun of it, I created a [Basic jsFiddle Demo Version](http://jsfiddle.net/pXQwD/1/).

---

**Note:** Always use `var` when you are defining a variable. Don't pollute the global scope.

Comment: It's a great solution. I don't know if it would work with my case. First when I call the function I can't pass any values. I suppose this could be fixed. Also I need a lot of versitility, the kind that handling a string does EG: with a string I could simply create a function that parses it and let's me modify the condition, add two conditions, change actions too. Maybe there is a way to stringify it and change it back or to parse the function and modify it. (I don't know if it's necessary to do it I'm just brainstorming) I'm sorry if I can't be more explicative, this little box doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Change your arrays from this:

```
conditions = [enemyNear(), mySpeed()>5, 1=1];
```

To this:

```
conditions = [
    function() { return enemyNear() },  // or just enemyNear
    function() { return mySpeed() > 5 },
    function() { return 1 == 1 } // 1 = 1?
];
```

With your current code, your functions are being called and `conditions` becomes an array of the outputs of those functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
condition = [
    enemyNear,
    function() { return mySpeed() > 5; },
    function() { return 1 == 1; }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your *functions* in the `array`, not call them, otherwise you are storing the *result* of the functions in the array.

```
function enemyNear() {}
function walk() {}

conditions = [enemyNear]
actions = [walk]

behaviour = function() {
  if(conditions[randomNumber]()) {
    actions[randomNumber]();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Simple. Use eval()

```
var behavior;
eval("behavior = function() { if (enemyNear()) walk(); }");
behavior();
```

Comment: The use of `eval` is discouraged. The better way is to store functions and then call each of them

Comment: The question sounds for me like a self programming behavior is required. For that, eval() is required.

Comment: @Tyron: Why would you use `eval` and not an anonymous function?

Comment: @Blender
Because the OP wants to generate anonymous functions, not define them.

Comment: The string you are evaling is completely static, it therefore made no sense to use eval.

Comment: @Tyron: What's the difference?

Comment: Esailija: Because it's the OPs example? O.o
Blender: Define = Function behavior is known at Runtime; Generate = Function behavior is not known at runtime. It wouldn't be much of an evolutionary AI if it only used predefined functions.

Comment: @Tyron: So why do you consider `eval` to be the proper tool for this job and not an anonymous function (or a function that creates an anonymous function)?

Comment: @Blender: How do you generate an anonymous function with code that's been generated at runtime?

Comment: @Tyron: You create the function with another function.